# Is it possible to use ThingsBoard with virtual I2C?

Tags: thingsboard

I saw that Thingsboard can send RPC requests (https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/action-nodes/#rpc-call-request-node). This example shows to send values to GPIO.

I was wondering if I can send values to the I2C physical devices connected to Raspberry Pi's.

And if I am using i2c-stub in order to create virtual I2C devices, how can I connect them to Thingsboard?
So far I am using i2cset and i2cset on RPi's to read and write virtual sensors.

Thanks,
Felipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this guide:
https://thingsboard.io/docs/samples/raspberry/gpio/

Core points:

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
...
if data['method'] == 'getGpioStatus':
    client.publish(msg.topic.replace('request', 'response'), get_gpio_status(), 1)
elif data['method'] == 'setGpioStatus':
    set_gpio_status(data['params']['pin'], data['params']['enabled'])
    client.publish(msg.topic.replace('request', 'response'), get_gpio_status(), 1)
    client.publish('v1/devices/me/attributes', get_gpio_status(), 1)
```

You can define your own functions and RPC method names for I2C (instead of using **get_gpio_status** and **set_gpio_status**)